# file persmissions for a group on FTP server (vsftp)

Tags: permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I've set up an FTPS server on an EC2 linux machine using VSFTPD, I changed the `file_open_mode` and `local_umask` in vsftpd.conf file to

```
local_umask=0007
file_open_mode=0777
```

This indeed give the `rwx` permissions to both the **owner and the group** as needed for the uploaded file (equivalent to the umask `770=777-007`).

I have 2 users that connect to this ftp server, they are part of the same Linux group `ftpusers`.

The problem is that when user 1 uploads a file to the server, the user 2 is not able to retrieve it using curl, I get 550 error : `RETR 550 : Unable to open file`, same error using FileZilla.

However, if user 2 uploads a file to the ftp server with the same file permissions, user 1 is able to download it both using curl and using filezilla.

What should I do to allow each user download/retrieve the files uploaded by the other user ? I've already put them in the same usergroup.

**Note:** This problem is solved if I set the permissions to 777 (read, write, execute for everyone), but this seems dangerous, the ftps server will store some important files.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :

I needed to use `chgroup` on the folders of interest to add permissions for the whole user group to access the files in these folders.